# Function in scrabble type game not working - MIT 6.0001 P-Set 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I can't figure out why my code for MIT's 6.0001, PS3, problem 3 is allowing a hand to be made with insufficient letters, ex: for the word 'Rapture', I'm getting `True` with the letters `{'r': 1, 'a': 3, 'p': 2, 'e': 1, 't': 1, 'u': 1}` when I test it inside of the game. However, when I the code separately, I'm getting `False`.

Below is the code inside the game.

```
if l_word in word_list:
    in_list = True
else:
    in_list = False

# Make word into list
w_holder = []
for let in l_word:
    w_holder.append(let)

# Compare word to hand
for let in w_holder:
    if let in h_holder:
        h_holder.pop(let)
        can_make = True
    else:
        can_make = False

if in_list is True and can_make is True:
    return True
else:
    return False
```

Below is the code I'm using to test it as a separate module:

```
word = "Rapture"
hand = {'r': 1, 'a': 3, 'p': 2, 't': 1, 'u': 2}

word_list = ["hot", "day", "face", "holl", "rapture", "honey"]

# Declare variables
l_word = word.lower()
h_holder = hand.copy()
can_make = ""

if l_word in word_list:
    in_list = True
else:
    in_list = False

# Make word into list
w_holder = []
for let in l_word:
    w_holder.append(let)

# Compare word to hand
for let in w_holder:
    if let in h_holder:
        h_holder.pop(let)
        can_make = True
    else:
        can_make = False

if in_list is True and can_make is True:
    print("True")
else:
    print("False")

print("Can make is" , can_make)
print("In list is" , in_list)
```

[Below is the zip file that contains the code and test code for the game that I'm trying to work on:](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-0001-introduction-to-computer-science-and-programming-in-python-fall-2016/assignments/PS3.zip)

Comment: "isn't working" isn't specific enough. Please [edit] your question and describe _exactly_ what the problem is.

Comment: Done. Thanks for the feedback. Let me know if what I posted makes sense.

Comment: That's definitely an improvement. One thing I don't understand, a comment in your code says `# Make word into dictionary`, but the variable `w_holder` is a list, not a dictionary.

Comment: Comment should say "list". I started with a dictionary, but I switched to a list because I thought it worked just as well. Not sure if that's what's wrong, but I'll edit that above.

Comment: Rieley: In the second snippet of code in your question, what printed value is wrong? When i run it as shown, it says `can_make` is `False`, and if I add an `'e'` to `hand` it says  `can_make` is `True` — which seems correct.

Comment: Martineau - That's what I'm getting as well. The issue is when I test the code in the top snippet, which is functionally the same as the bottom, I get "True".

Comment: Sorry, I don't see that code inside the game. I think you need to post [mre] that demonstrate the really code working.

Comment: I've figured out the issue. Thanks for the help.